# Getting fcron and RVM work together

Tags: cron, rvm

I'm trying to make [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) and [fcron](http://fcron.free.fr/) work together. Apparently fcron does not read directly or indirectly any sort of env variables. Which makes RVM futile and scripts fail.

I have this script which works with RVM ruby-1.9.3, rvm-gems etc. Although I tried implementing the following wrapper:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x -v

# load rvm ruby
source /home/user/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p0

#ruby /usr/local/bin/morula -s hakmem update
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/script -s username update
```

My fcrontab just executes the '/home/user/test.sh' (the above script).

I've tried putting SHELL, GEM_HOME, PATH, LANG and other variables on fcrontab -e but nothing worked so far. Any ideas are welcome.

Best regards

Comment: your script looks good, does it fail ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above script did not work. I had to set much additional variables on the crontab for this to work. On FreeBSD I use the following:

```
# etc/crontab - crontab for FreeBSD
PATH=/home/www/atma/.rvm/bin:$PATH
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
#GEM_HOME=/home/www/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125:/home/www/atma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global
GEM_HOME=/home/www/atma/.gems
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/bash
#minute hour    mday    month   wday    who command
30 10 * * * /home/www/atma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby /home/www/atma/opt/scripts/pharmanights
#> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Here is a detailed blogpost about RVM + fcron http://www.convalesco.org/index.php/archives/2385